# Internal type cannot be found by compiler

Tags: c++, class, templates

I'm getting the following errors:

```
Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&'  
Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error   3   error C2065: 'Item' : undeclared identifier 
Error   4   error C2065: 'Order' : undeclared identifier
```

for this line of code:

```
template <class Item, class Order>
Iterator& DLinkedOrderedList<Item, Order>::Iterator::operator++(){}
```

If I'm not mistaken, the above line is the correct syntax for the function to return a type Iterator&?

Comment: C++1x idea: Allow `this` (or `*this`) in place of the return type of a non-static method. It's probably the most common thing to return after `void`.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah the prof needs us to return by reference, so I'll definitely need to use this or *this (I didn't add in the appropriate code yet inside the function definition when I asked this question).

Comment: The comment wasn't really aimed at your code. The C++ language is still in active development, and I was suggesting a future direction there.

Answer (score 2):

You need `DLinkedOrderedList<Item, Order>::` for `Iterator`, as the return type is unknown outside the class declaration:

```
template <class Item, class Order>
DLinkedOrderedList<Item, Order>::Iterator& DLinkedOrderedList<Item, Order>::Iterator::operator++(){}
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

And if you don't like that long redundant thing, you can use `auto` and `->`:

```
template <class Item, class Order>
auto DLinkedOrderedList<Item, Order>::Iterator::operator++() -> Iterator& {}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I use the auto and -> method, it works perfectly fine. But when I use the normal return syntax it doesn't work for some reason: 
    DLinkedOrderedList<Item, Order>::Iterator& DLinkedOrderedList<Item, Order>::Iterator::operator++(){}

Comment: @user3007481: You're welcome. Both should work properly. Maybe you missed something, a typo for example.

Comment: @user3007481 Maybe the iterator class is not publicly visible?

Comment: The Iterator class is publicly visible inside DLinkedOrderedList in this case. Still have not figured out why the auto and -> method works yet, and the classic syntax does not.

Comment: @user3007481: This `->` syntax was specifically invented so that the `-> Iterator` part appears after the compiler has seen `DLinkedOrderedList<Item, Order>::`, not before.